# Concerned that skipping ab exercises will have negative implications

Tags: abdominals

I find that I never have time to focus on abs when I work out. If I continue to strengthen other parts of my body (I consistently do squats, deadlift, benchpress, shoulderpress) and continue to neglect working on core strength, will I run into problems?

Comment: You squat and deadlift. Don't those work your abs and core?

Comment: I was under the impression that squats and deadlift almost exclusively target legs/back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You squat, deadlift, and press. While these each stress specific muscles more than others (presses working more shoulder strength, deadlifting working more legs and back, *et cetera*), they are all whole-body exercises that work the core. If done heavy, these exercises demand and develop a significant amount of core strength, including the abdominals, as stabilizers. Along with your lower back, they isometrically hold your trunk in place for heavy lifting.

Answer (score 3):

I like this [article about abs by Mark Rippetoe](http://startingstrength.com/articles/abs_rippetoe.pdf).

> As the loads pass 200 and then 300+ pounds, it becomes 
>   enough of a challenge for the now more experienced lifter that a helluva lot of ab work is required to 
>   squat and pull properly. At weights above this range, most lifters find that a belt helps them produce 
>   harder ab contractions and therefore maintain better spinal stability, and this is why it is common that 
>   a lifter’s first squat workout with a belt produces new levels of ab fatigue.